# Software for System Reliability Analysis

Tags: windows, simulation, statistics

I am trying to find a software (free if possible) to simulate System Reliability.

More specifically, I am looking to simulate systems with sub-components that each have probabilistic (and not deterministic) failure rates (Probabilistic density functions) and if possible probabilistic repair times (MTTR).

If possible, the software should handle multiple failure causes for a single system component.

My objective is to calculate a system probabilistic reliability function and an overall system MTTR based on time-dependent simulations.

The current software I know of is Blocksim from reliasoft (too expensive) and openreliability, but if I'm not mistaken they do not deal with probabilistic failure rates.

If you know a package on R or Python that does the trick I am interested in that too.

Thank you for your help!